# joining sql views with alternate values instead of nulls

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

hopefully this chart makes sense...

the problem is that I have many columns in the many-many table, how can I get all the column values in a view, without doing `ISNULL` for each row?
(sql server 10.5)

```
 ITEM
+------+
| ID   |
|------|
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
+------+

 LANGUAGE
+-------+---------+
| ID    |  Name   |
|-------+---------|
| 1     | English |
| 2     | French  |
+-------+---------+

 Item Names
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| ItemID   | LangId  |   Name     |   Color    |
|----------+---------+------------+------------|
| 1        |   1     |  apple     |  red       |
| 1        |   2     |  pomme     |  rouge     |
| 2        |   1     |  orange    |  orange    |
| 3        |   1     |  bannana   |  yellow    |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

desired view

```
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| ItemID   | LangId  |   Name     |   Color    |
|----------+---------+------------+------------|
| 1        |   1     |  apple     |  red       |
| 1        |   2     |  pomme     |  rouge     |
| 2        |   1     |  orange    |  orange    |
| 2        |   2     |  orange    |  orange    | <--- added automatically
| 3        |   1     |  bannana   |  yellow    |
| 3        |   2     |  bannana   |  yellow    | <--- added automatically
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

because I'm trying to create a view there are certain limitations:

The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in any other way, such as through the following:

- An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
- A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable.

I an however create multiple views, which is how I've gotten around some of these restrictions before. we can assume that I already have this table

intermediary view:

```
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| ItemID   | LangId  |   Name     |   Color    |
|----------+---------+------------+------------|
| 1        |   1     |  apple     |  red       |
| 1        |   2     |  pomme     |  rouge     |
| 2        |   1     |  orange    |  orange    |
| 3        |   1     |  bannana   |  yellow    |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

as well as:

```
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| ItemID   | LangId  |   Name     |   Color    |
|----------+---------+------------+------------|
| 1        |   1     |  apple     |  red       |
| 1        |   2     |  pomme     |  rouge     |
| 2        |   1     |  orange    |  orange    |
| 2        |   2     |  -         |  -         |
| 3        |   1     |  bannana   |  yellow    |
| 3        |   2     |  -         |  -         |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

these are some of the views:

view1 - all combinations

[image]

view2 - all combinations with languages
[image]

the corresponding SQL:

```
SELECT     dbo.view1.ItemID, dbo.view1.LanguageID, dbo.ItemLanguages.Name, dbo.ItemLanguages.Color
FROM         dbo.ItemLanguages RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.view1 ON dbo.ItemLanguages.LanguageID = dbo.view1.LanguageID AND dbo.ItemLanguages.ItemID = dbo.view1.ItemID
```

result of view 2
[image]

here is the test database with the views and tables: http://pastebin.com/4BpBSmHY

Comment: Just trying to understand the question... So because FruitId 1 has a FruitName for both languages, no new rows.  And since FruitId 2 and 3 only have a value for English, a row is automatically generated for all other languages?

Comment: What if there is another language 'German'. So, fruit ID=1 should have one more row for the third language. Then which fruit should be duplicated with 'German' ? Apple or Pomme

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d016f/8. However, this cannot be the final answer. You need to answer above question first.

Comment: if there is is german, unless the table gets updated with `Apfel` `Orange` and `Banane`, it would default to the English names (or french if English is missing, but that part is not that important)

Comment: I've also updated the question, with some of the limitations of SQL views that prevent this fiddle from working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I've been able to do it is using `ISNULL`

```
SELECT     dbo.view1.ItemID,
    dbo.view1.LanguageID,
    ISNULL(dbo.ItemLanguages.Name,
      (SELECT     TOP (1) Name
        FROM          dbo.ItemLanguages AS x
        WHERE      (ItemID = dbo.view1.ItemID))) AS Name,
    ISNULL(dbo.ItemLanguages.Color,
      (SELECT     TOP (1) Color
        FROM          dbo.ItemLanguages AS x
        WHERE      (ItemID = dbo.view1.ItemID))) AS Color,
    CASE  
        WHEN  dbo.ItemLanguages.ItemID is NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as valid

FROM         dbo.ItemLanguages RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                 dbo.view1 ON dbo.ItemLanguages.ItemID = dbo.view1.ItemID
                          AND dbo.ItemLanguages.LanguageID = dbo.view1.LanguageID
```

the reason why I don't like this approach is that I'm doing this across many more columns. I have the notion that doing multiple SELECTS would slow down the result drastically.

I though I'd be able to just check if the row exists like with the `CASE

            WHEN  dbo.ItemLanguages.ItemID is NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as valid`
and then call the select once and populate all the columns

.. in a view